# How to centre text over image without separate div tag?

Tags: html, css

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d35QD/

I would like to know how to centre text over an image without using a div tag. I am creating a navigation menu and would prefer not to wrap each button within a separate div tag. Probably very simple to do but I'm new to CSS :-P .

At the moment I'm using absolute positioning. This would be ok if text was displayed in exactly the same way in all browsers, but obviously it's not so I need another method.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.htm"><img class="navbutton" src="http://www.cawyatt.co.uk/test-top.png" alt="Website Navigation. Home Button" title="Home" /><p class="homebutton">HOME</p></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<!-- end .nav -->
</div>


ul, ol, dl {
padding:0;
margin:0;
list-style:none;
}

#nav {
background-image: url(http://www.cawyatt.co.uk/test-bottom.png);
width:120px;
height:115px;
position:relative;
}

#nav img{
height:115px;
width:120px;
}

.navbutton {
-webkit-transition:opacity 0.7s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:opacity 0.7s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:opacity 0.7s ease-in-out;
transition:opacity 0.7s ease-in-out;
float:left;
}

a:hover img.navbutton {
opacity:0;
}

.homebutton {
position:absolute;
left:1px;
top:60px;
color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:16px;
}
```

EDIT:

The methods suggested below work when it's just one button, but not when there is more than one. All text gets centred over the first button. I have created another fiddle to show what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/3JCKB/

EDIT 2:

Thanks for all the help guys. Managed to fix it by changing the p tags to span tags. This works because span is an inline element where as p is a block level element :-)

You can see the finished code here: http://jsfiddle.net/yTACT/

I have also cleaned up the code and removed unnecessary classes. Thanks again!

Comment: Maybe you can use image as background and center text over it ... background-image:url('paper.gif');

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3YWPx/

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/d35QD/10/

Comment: Those methods work when just creating one button, but when I add more all text is centred on the first button. I have created another fiddle to show you what I mean:

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3JCKB/

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. Managed to fix it by changing the p tags to span tags. This works because span is an inline element where as p is a block level element :-)

You can see the finished code here: http://jsfiddle.net/yTACT/

I have also cleaned up the code and removed unnecessary classes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There are two good methods of doing this:

**1:**

```
.homebutton{
     position: relative;
     right: 120px //width of image
     width: 120px;
     text-align: center;
}
```

**2:**

Remove the image, and set it as a background image of `.homebutton`

```
.homebutton{
     background: url('http://www.cawyatt.co.uk/test-top.png') no-repeat left top;
     width: 120px;
     height: 115px;
     text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: First method works when just using 1 button, but when i add more all text is centred over first button. I can't use the second method as I am already using a css bg image for the hover effect. I have created another fiddle to show what I mean:

Comment: Your .navbuttontext is positioned absolutely, I suspect that this is the problem.

Comment: If I change that the whole menu "breaks".

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. Managed to fix it by changing the p tags to span tags. This works because span is an inline element where as p is a block level element :-) . 

You can see the finished code here: http://jsfiddle.net/yTACT/ . 

I have also cleaned up the code and removed unnecessary classes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to center only horizontally or both horizontally and vertically. Anyway, you can try to do like this :

```
p{
    width: 120px; // Same width as your image
    text-align: center; // Center text horizontally
}
```

Comment: Those methods work when just creating one button, but when I add more all text is centred on the first button. I have created another fiddle to show you what I mean:

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. Managed to fix it by changing the p tags to span tags. This works because span is an inline element where as p is a block level element :-) . 

You can see the finished code here: http://jsfiddle.net/yTACT/ . 

I have also cleaned up the code and removed unnecessary classes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

`#nav li > a > p { text-align: center; width: 100%;}`

Sets the width of the paragraph to 100% the anchor width, then aligns text to center in that area.

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/d35QD/12/)